# In python is there a data structure that can use duplicate strings as index?

Tags: python, string

In the following code snippet for text summary, it is intended to store an integer/importance value corresponding to each sentence in a paragraph.I tried using dictionary , but have issues with similar indices Is there a data structure in python that can make use of a string as an index where single string may occur multiple times?

```
line = fr.readline() 
relevance = {}
while line:

     line_value = select(line)
     relevance[line] = line_value #error in this line
     line = fr.readline()
```

Comment: A [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? (And dictionaries sure *can* use strings as keys.)

Comment: If you want to loop over the lines of a file, `for line in f:` does that.

Comment: Running the code should suggest the problem (that you're not using a dict, you're using a list): `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is that "select()" doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best data structure depends on what you then need to do with it.

A dictionary might work. However:

1. standard dictionaries are unordered
2. duplicate strings might need  special handling.

If neither is a problem, simply change `[]` to `{}` in your code.

Another alternative is to have a list of `(line,value)` tuples. This will preserve the ordering of data and duplicates, but will not offer efficient string-based lookups.

Comment: OrderedDictionary will preserve order